# Publish two versions of the same app using Google iFrame

Tags: android-management-api, android-managed-profile

We have been using Android Management apis and integrated an iFrame to publish private apps to profiles and groups. Is there any way we can publish two versions of the same app? e.g. one versions for test group and when it gets approved then push it to production group.

The problem we are facing right now is that whenever we push an update, the app gets updated on both the groups.

Answer (score 0):

No, the play store won't allow a second app with the same `packageName` to be uploaded, an error will be thrown stating that `packageName already exists`

This applies to any google play store, if you uploaded the APP on private play store, you cannot upload it on the public play store and vice versa.

Now for the problem you are facing, you can use a workaround :

1. Set `"appAutoUpdatePolicy": "NEVER"` in the policy so that the APP doesn't get automatically updated.
2. Push updates by specifying the `minimumVersionCode` in the policy of the application and send it out to the devices or groups that you want the APP to be updated.

```
{
   "packageName": "com.example",
   "aliasName": "Silverline MDM Client",
   "installType": "REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP",
   "lockTaskAllowed": false,
   "defaultPermissionPolicy": "DEFAULT",
   "minimumVersionCode" : "36"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I will definitely try it and post my findings here :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en) to set up an open, closed, or internal test for your app. This way, you can let your testing team test and review the app before releasing it to production. It is also possible to add testing tracks to a private app in the managed play iFrame through the advanced edit functionality mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/managed-play-iframe#private-apps_1). You can refer to the sample [policy](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#applicationpolicy) below on how to install test track app using its trackId.

{
"packageName": "com.sample.testtrack",
"installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
"accessibleTrackIds": [
4699274789592568069
]
}